# MC AMPScript RetrieveSalesforceObjects() hitting governor limits

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, governorlimits, marketing-cloud-connect

Imagine a scenario where we have a Marketing Cloud connected to a Sales Cloud. Around 1500 campaign members will enter a journey at approximately same time and then each of those members will receive an email that includes the AMPScript function RetrieveSalesforceObjects().

If each of those 1500 emails includes the RetrieveSalesforceObjects() function, will it hit the Apex governor limits? Is this a scenario I need to address or will it be taken care of by the MC Connector?

I would also appreciate any documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Providing that you are using Connected App authentication in Marketing Cloud Connect, then API calls made by Marketing Cloud Connect (for AMPscript Salesforce functions, Data Stream and other interoperability) will not count towards your SOAP API limits (with the exception of email tracking data which uses the Bulk API, which will count towards your limit).

However, a word of caution. The RetrieveSalesforceObjects function is very slow and if you are sending an email to a large number of Subscribers at the same time (which you are), this will impact send performance. In one test I ran, approximately 400 emails were sent in 30 minutes and we calculated that it would take 1.5 years for the send to finish!

I would recommend that you consider syncing the Objects in Data Stream and use a Lookup AMPscript function to get the values from the Synchronized DE to avoid this performance limitation.